# Define $S=\{(x,f(x))\}$ (a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ ), where $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Define $S=\{(x,f(x))\}$ (a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ ), where $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. I was trying to prove that $S$ is a closed set. It is clearly true by thinking of the graph, but I have trouble proving it algebraically...

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "algebraically." It might be easier to prove the complement is open.

Comment: I was thinking how to prove it using the $\epsilon$-definition of closed sets.

Comment: Try looking for the general closed graph theorem

Answer (score 1):

I will outline how to prove that $U=\mathbb R^2\setminus S$ is open.

Given $(x_0,y_0)\in U$, so $y_0\neq f(x_0)$. Let $\epsilon=|y_0-f(x_0)|$.

Since $f$ is continuous, find $\delta>0$ so that if $|x-x_0|<\delta$ then $|f(x) - f(x_0)|<\epsilon.$

Now take the set $V=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2\mid d((x,y),(x_0,y_0))<\min(\epsilon,\delta)\}$.

Show that $V\subseteq \mathbb R^2\setminus S$.

So $\mathbb R^2\setminus S$ is open, and $S$ is closed.

Comment: I followed until the point "show that $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 \backslash S$". I think that would involve proving that $y \not= f(x)$ as defined before?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try and do it directly. Let $(x_0,y_0)$ be a limit point of $S$. We must show that this point is actually contained in $S$. As $(x_0,y_0)$ is a limit point, we can find a sequence of points $\{(x_i,f(x_i))\}_{n=1}^\infty$ in $S$ which converges to $(x_0,y_0)$. In particular, this means that $x_i\to x_0$ and $f(x_i)\to y_0$. But now by sequential continuity, it must be that $f(x_i)\to f(x_0)$, i.e. $f(x_0)=y_0$. Thus the limit point is in fact $(x_0,f(x_0)$, which is contained in $S$.